# In C++ how do I insert strings into a set?

Tags: c++, set

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <set>

int main(){
    
    std::string text;
    std::getline(std::cin, text);
    
    std::set<std::string> filter;
    
    for(int i = 0; i< text.length(); i++){
        filter.insert(text[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error with my code, it says:

> no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type' {aka 'char'} to 'std::initializer_list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>'

Do I need to convert each one into a `char`, then insert into the set?

Comment: Can you describe, in plain English, with a few examples, what your program is supposed to do? If you were asked to design a new car model, describing the end result as, simply, "going forward by pressing the gas pedal", won't be a sufficient description.

Comment: Do you want your set to contain words (strings) or letters (chars)?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to insert individual `char` values into a `std::set` of `std::string` values, thus [`set::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) is expecting you to give it either a `std::string` or a `std::initializer_list<std::string>` as input.  But neither one of those can be constructed from a single `char`, hence the error.

However, `std::string` does have another constructor that takes a `char` and a count as input, eg:

```
std::set<std::string> filter;
    
for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
    filter.insert(std::string(1, text[i]));
}
```

Otherwise, create a `std::set` of `char` values instead:

```
std::set<char> filter;
    
for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
    filter.insert(text[i]);
}
```

Comment: The first solution is cleaner with `emplace`: `filter.emplace(1, text[i]);` but I see the point you wanted to illustrate with the explicit ctor call.

Answer (score 2):

`text[i]` is a character not a string,

if you are trying to chop up the input into several word you need to do that yourself.

If thats what you want then either

- use `cin>>word` in a loop , this will pick out individual words for you, rather than getline which reads the whole input as one string
- create a `stringstream` over text and use `ss>>word` on that
- or walk down text char by char skipping white space (the fiddlyest way)